# Which version of ChromeDriver/Selenium should I use?

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium in docker and it worked fine, but today something went wrong
I have this code in my docker file to install latest versions of chrome and chromedriver:

```
# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
```

today when I try to initialize the driver, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90
Current browser version is 89.0.4389.128 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

I already had such issues and I know about selenium and chromedriver compatibility, but I just can't find a solution right now. Everyone says I need to use latest versions of both, but it doesn't help. Maybe someone had such issue too?

Answer (score 0):

This should be resolved now. See this thread in the angular/webdriver-manager repo: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/491.

TL;DR

There is an endpoint to say which version of chromedriver is latest (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE). As of 4/13 and much of 4/14, this was returning chromedriver version 90.*. From the code you provided - this API is being leveraged. The problem is chrome never released version 90 [(see chrome release schedule)](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule), so there was a mismatch. Whoever manages that api reverted it to 89, so your setup should now work and install a compatible version of chromedriver.